# Visual Studio encerrando Debug inesperadamente (IIS erro)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debug, iis

Venho compartilhar uma solução que pra mim pelo menos funcionou depois de varias tentativas. Porem primeiramente vou explanar o problema ocorrido:

Certo vez utilizando windows 7 tive um problema ao iniciar o debug de um Webapp ao clicar no input de url do navegador, iniciado uma nova aba ou em quais quer input que minha view tinha automaticamente o debug se encerrava e o browser era fechado(Foram realizados os mesmos procedimentos nos browsers: IE, Edge, Mozilla, Chrome e Opera)

Output window me mostrava sempre erros do IIS tais como [12712], [6392] dentre outros, sempre alternando o erro mas sem descrição.

EventViewer me mostrava um aviso do IIS:

> The directory specified for caching compressed content
>   C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool
>   is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

Alterei permissão de diretório dentre outras coisas no IIS porém sem sucesso e sem encontrar respostas em forums de diversos paises(Talvez pelos termos buscados e códigos de erro).

Comment: Embora essa informação seja útil, você postou simplesmente como uma resposta. O ideal seria você criar uma pergunta com o problema e depois publicar a sua solução como resposta.

Comment: Apenas dividi os textos...mas ok feito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enfim cheguei a seguinte alteração que resolveu o problema de modo inexplicável pra mim que fora a seguinte:

No VS ir em Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects

Desabilitar a opção que diz para encerrar o Debug quando a janela do browser fechar.

Realmente inexplicável ja que eu não encerrava a janela, o Log de aviso do iis parou de aparecer, e nem havia interação antes fora abrir abas e clicar em inputs.

Porem se estiver alguém como eu que está sofrendo formatando Windows reinstalando seus 30Gb de visual studio trocando versão e buscando solução sem encontrar. Funcionou perfeitamente para mim, nenhum erro apresentado mais, a performance das aplicações está perfeito(Debug e Release).